# Pegar data atributo de último elemento de uma lista

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-attribute

Bom dia pessoal, estou montando um sisteminha que ao clicar em um botão eu adiciono um `<li>` no último registro da linha, porém cada `<li>` possui um *data-id* numérico para diferenciação, ou seja, eu precisaria saber qual o último *data-id* para poder adicionar + 1 ao clicar no botão.

Tentei como código abaixo, mas não funcionou, ele só pega o primeiro *data-id* (eu preciso do último) e não adiciona + 1 no segundo clique, apenas no primeiro.

```
$("#botaoexemplo").on("click", function() {
    var contagem = $('.dd-item').attr('data-id');
    contagem++;
    $("#dd-list-geral").append('<li class="dd-item" data-id="'+contagem+'"><div class="dd-handle"> Item 100 </div></li>');
    console.log(valor, dado);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar *last* para pegar o último item de um array de elementos no seu seletor:

```
var ultimoId = $('.dd-item:last').data('id');
```

Referência: https://api.jquery.com/last/

Answer (score 2):

Use a função `.last()`

```
$("#botaoexemplo").on("click", function() {
    var contagem = $('.dd-item').last().attr('data-id');
    contagem++;
    $("#dd-list-geral").append('<li class="dd-item" data-id="'+contagem+'"><div class="dd-handle"> Item 100 </div></li>');
    console.log(valor, dado);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Para pegar o ultimo elemento você pode utilizar o seletor `:last`

Por exemplo, para pegar a ultima linha de uma table:

`$('table tr:last')`

Nota que o seu `append` já insere na ultima posição, então o `:last` depois do `append` será a linha recém inclusa.